# Increment 2 different parameters separately in a for loop

Tags: python

I have the following code. The file `file.txt` contains a list of variables. Some of them should be `str` type and others should be `int` type.

```
var = [None] * 3
j = 0

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:       
    content = f.readline().split(";")

for i in range(2, 5):
    var[j] = int(content[i])
    j += 1
```

Instead of incrementing `j` manually I'd like to do it in a cleaner way (e.g. within the 'instructions' of the for loop, or something like that.

What would be a shorter/better way to handle this task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, j in enumerate(range(2,5)):
   var[j] = int(content[i])
```

Also, you don't need to initialize `var` at all - just use a list comprehension:

```
var = [int(content[i]) for i in range(2, 5)]
```

---

Another approach (may be less Pythonic/less efficient/less readable):

You can `zip` two `range`s together:

```
for i, j in zip(range(len(range(2, 5))), range(2,5)):
   var[j] = int(content[i])
```

You know that the second range is `range(2, 5)` and want the first range to be from zero to `len(range(2, 5))` - that's `range(len(range(2, 5)))`.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to count the current iteration index is by using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

```
for j, i in enumerate(range(2, 5)):
    var[j] = int(content[i])
```

(There's no need to initialize `j = 0` in this case.)

However, your example code would usually just be written as:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:       
    content = f.readline().split(";")

var = [int(x) for x in content[2:5]]
```

which uses language features such as

- a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) (`[2:5]`) to select a part of a list
- a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list from an input sequence